# Exchange Server 2019 CU12 and Outlook certificate warnings for GoDaddy mail cert

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, ssl, exchange

I just upgraded 2003 Small business server to Exchange Server 2019 CU12 on Windows Server 2022. I've had a GoDaddy mail certificate for a few years now and I rekeyed it for the new server.

Some details:
Exchange server is danube.clientdomain.com.au
Mail cert CN is mail.clientdomain.com.au
(I installed Windows servers with an internal domain named the same as the external domain, as per Microsoft's recommendations)

I had to upgrade Office to 2016 to get a version that will connect to 2019 Exchange Server while still allowing install on Windows 2007. But I tested Office 2021 on Windows 10 and it has the same problem.

Which is: When running Outlook from a domain-joined PC, I get a certificate warning that the certificate "mail.clientdomain.com.au" doesn't match the mail server "danube.clientdomain.com.au"

This warning occurs twice every time I run Outlook. I also get warnings for autodiscover at certain times.

Without purchasing additional SSL certs or a multi-subject cert, is there some way I can configure IIS/Exchange/DNS to prevent these warnings? I followed Microsoft's 'how-to' for installing the cert and configuring DNS etc, but I'm pretty sure something is not quite right.

Output from some relevant Exchange cmdlets:

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-OutlookAnywhere | Select Server,InternalHostName,ExternalHostName

Server InternalHostname           ExternalHostname

---

DANUBE danube.clientdomain.com.au mail.clientdomain.com.au

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-MAPIVirtualDirectory | Select Server,InternalURL,ExternalURL

Server InternalUrl                             ExternalUrl

---

DANUBE https://danube.clientdomain.com.au/mapi https://mail.clientdomain.com.au/mapi

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-OABVirtualDirectory | Select Server,InternalURL,ExternalURL

Server InternalUrl                          ExternalUrl

---

DANUBE https://mail.clientdomain.com.au/OAB https://mail.clientdomain.com.au/OAB

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory | Select Server,InternalURL,ExternalURL

Server InternalUrl                                        ExternalUrl

---

DANUBE https://mail.clientdomain.com.au/ews/exchange.asmx https://mail.clientdomain.com.au/ews/exchange.asmx

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ClientAccessService | Select Name,AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri

Name   AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri

---

DANUBE https://danube.clientdomain.com.au/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ExchangeCertificate | fl Subject,CertificateDomains,Services

Subject            : CN=mail.clientdomain.com.au
CertificateDomains : {mail.clientdomain.com.au, www.mail.clientdomain.com.au}
Services           : IMAP, POP

Subject            : C=AU, S=WA, L=Perth, O=ClientName, OU=ITdept, CN=mail.clientdomain.com.au
CertificateDomains : {mail.clientdomain.com.au, clientdomain.com.au}
Services           : None

Subject            : CN=mail.clientdomain.com.au
CertificateDomains : {mail.clientdomain.com.au, www.mail.clientdomain.com.au}
Services           : IMAP, POP, IIS, SMTP

Subject            : CN=Microsoft Exchange Server Auth Certificate
CertificateDomains : {}
Services           : SMTP

Subject            : CN=Danube
CertificateDomains : {Danube, Danube.clientdomain.com.au}
Services           : IIS, SMTP

Subject            : CN=WMSvc-SHA2-DANUBE
CertificateDomains : {WMSvc-SHA2-DANUBE}
Services           : None

Subject            : CN=clientdomain-DANUBE-CA, DC=clientdomain, DC=com, DC=au
CertificateDomains : {clientdomain-DANUBE-CA}
Services           : None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure all the internalURL as the same as the externalURL: mail.clientdomain.com.au including Autodiscover service, and create a new A record in internal DNS server to point mail.clientdomain.com.au to the IP of the Exchange server.

Comment: Yup that worked. Should have been obvious I guess. Following the Microsoft help made it not-so-obvious.